# How to add a column to Laravel Nova resource

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I'm trying to add a custom column to the Laravel Nova resource.

In the fields the columns that exist in database can be added like:

```
public function fields(NovaRequest $request) {
     ID::make()->sortable(),
     Text::make('Country')->sortable();
}
```

But, I wanted to add a custom column that doesn't exist in that database table. Its value can be obtained by using Eloquent:

```
$count = Hostel::where('country_id', $country_id)
            ->distinct('type_id')
            ->whereMonth('created_at', Carbon::now()->month )
            ->count();
```

where `$country_id` is the ID in the resouce.

How would I acheive this? and making sure this field doesn't appear when using Add Resource? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know if you are using Nova 3 or 4, but the way of doing it is the same. I do not have the Nova package, so I am 100% using the documentation, I may be missing something in my code, but it should perfectly work.

You need to use a [`computed`](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/resources/fields.html#computed-fields) field. It will let you set what type of field it is going to be, but you must set the value of it, exactly what you need. In this case, I will use a [`Number`](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/resources/fields.html#number-field) field, but feel free to use `Text` or whatever you would like to:

```php
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\Number;

public function fields(NovaRequest $request)
{
    return [

        ID::make()
            ->sortable(),

        Text::make('Country')
            ->sortable(),

        Number::make('Amount of Hostels in Country', function () {
            return Hostel::where('country_id', $this->country_id)
                ->distinct('type_id')
                ->whereMonth('created_at', now()->month)
                ->count();
        })
            ->hideWhenCreating()
            ->hideWhenUpdating(),
    ];
}
```

I added `hideWhenCreating` and `hideWhenUpdating`, because you said you don't want it when adding a resource, but I also added hidden on update because it would make not much sense to see it when updating a resource. This field should be read only. In that case read the same page I shared before (`computed`), it has all the methods you need to hide them, make them read-only, etc.

Maybe, instead of using `hideWhenXXXXX`, you may be able to use `exceptOnForms`, but I do not know what `hideWhenXXXX` is running in teh background, check the method and see if it helps you.

Comment: Be aware, however, that this will mean a query per row. That may cause significant slowness in the list view. You're probably better off with an eager-loaded relationship you can count without incurring a per-row query.

Comment: @ceejayoz absolutely true! I did only add the basic part as I do not have it here to test code, and I can not do that part by memory, but 100% correct!

Comment: @ceejayoz looks so. It's significantly slow. How would I eager load?